# How to write if/else with jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write simple if/else in one line and simpler using jQuery selector. How can I do it?

I have a checkbox named `chkAgree` in my form. I am trying to handle its click event like below. I would like to write this code block more simpler with just once using jQuery selector. My IDE gives me warning that "Duplicated jQuery selector", so I think there is a way to solve this problem.
Regards

```
$("#chkAgree").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#divCheckboxes").show();
    } else {
        $("#divCheckboxes").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Like that. But better: `$("#chkAgree").on("click",function(){
        $("#divCheckboxes").toggle(this.checked); })` // or use "change"

Comment: Agreed with @mplungjan although I'd suggest using`change` for a checkbox instead of `click`

Comment: The plural "divCheckboxes" is suspect - you do know IDs need to be unique? If you have multiple elements with id="divCheckboxes" then you need to use a class instead

Answer (score 0):

You should rather store the selector value in a variable and for performance reasons do it outside the callback function, e.g:

```
var divCheckboxes = $("#divCheckboxes");
$("#chkAgree").click(function(){
  if(this.checked){
    divCheckboxes.show();
  }else{
    divCheckboxes.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: `$("#chkAgree").on("click",function(){ $("#divCheckboxes").toggle(this.checked); })`

Comment: this one works too, but I would still recommend you to save them in a variable (first line in my example) to avoid querying the DOM in the callback every time the function is called.

Comment: It will be called a maximum of two times per visit

Answer (score 0):

Use on.click instead of click or it will work only the first time.

```
var divCheckboxes = $("#divCheckboxes");
$("#chkAgree").on("click", function(){
   this.checked ? divCheckboxes.show() : divCheckboxes.hide();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#chkAgree").click(function(){
    $("#divCheckboxes").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: `$("#chkAgree").on("click",function(){ $("#divCheckboxes").toggle(this.checked); })`

Comment: This will still result in the 'Duplicated jQuery selector' error which the question is trying to avoid.